# Normalizing a large set of ratios

Tags: normalization, standardization

I have a problem that has been causing headaches. To set up the problem, here's what I have. Bear with me, since I'm trying to clarify the problem as much as possible:

- A large set of personnel
- These personnel have performance evaluations that are based on a number of criteria with a numerical value of 1 to 5.
- The individual performance traits are averaged to get the "trait average"
- Every evaluator (i.e., boss) has his/her own "cumulative average" that is an average of all of the evaluations they have done. This allows us to see how well an employee is doing compared to the boss's historical average. This cumulative average changes over time as the evaluator writes more evaluations. The cumulative average is attached to the individual trait average at the time the report was written.
- I am trying to compare these personnel across several subunits of the organization who all have different bosses (evaluators)
- I have a complete dataset of all of their evaluations, and want to use a ratio of the trait average/cumulative average to compare performance.
- I realize that I need to normalize (or standardize) the data in order to fairly compare people, since the denominator shifts according to an evaluators grading criteria.
- The personnel have multiple evaluations that all need to be factored in.

My question is how to best normalize. Do I need to normalize each individual evaluation trait average, each individual evaluation cumulative average, divide the two, then add the ratios for all the reports for that person and divide by the total number of evaluations for that individual to get an overall average of the ratios? This is my gut feeling, but I am uncertain. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The z-score will serve your purposes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score

This z-score normalizes to the range of responses provided by accounting for the variation and the difference between a given score and the mean score for all individuals.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the response! I've looked at z score as well, and I suppose my question would apply to using a z score or a normalization. The crux of the question is: should I calculate a z score for the numerator, then calculate a z score for the denominator, then divide the two? or should I divide the two first, then calculate a z score? Additionally, I think I need a z score for each individual performance evaluation prior to taking an average. I hope I didn't muddy the waters here. I am admittedly a statistics novice, and more of a database guy.

Comment: Would it not work just to normalize or standardize each score by boss and then sum?  i.e. boss1 gives z=0,  boss2 z=1, boss3 z=2, then employee score would be 3 or and average of 1.  It wouldn't matter if a boss scored high or low, because of the normalization/standardization.  <br> More simply, make an average of standardized scores for each individual where standardization is done by boss.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe, but a boss could have multiple people in the population that they wrote a performance report on. Additionally, a person can change bosses on a regular basis (government organization). If someone is above that boss's cumulative, we generally consider it to be a good evaluation, but we are trying to numerically determine the degree of "goodness" of an evaluation when compared to the population, and then rank everyone accordingly.

Comment: Would using a normalization (vice standardization) work. Using (x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin) to get a value between 0 and 1, I could normalize trait avg, normalize cumulative avg, take the ratio, then get an average of those normalized ratios for each person. Or would this be grossly inaccurate?